# plannar fit with odrpack

Tags: python, scipy, data-fitting

I am trying to use scipy.odr to get a best fit plane for some x, y, z points.

I define the plane equation implicitly as ax + by + cz + d = 0 and I perform a least squares (with scipy.linalg.lstsq) to provide the odr with an initial estimation.

The components of the beta vector (where beta = [a, b, c, d]) returned by the odr are of a magnitude between 1e167 and 1e172... Is such a result trustworthy? I find the numbers to be absurd...

Note that the points come from 3D scanning of a relatively flat face which is almost parallel to the xz plane (nearly vertical).

Here is the pprint() of the odr result:

```
'
Beta: [  3.14570111e-170   3.21821458e-169   4.49232028e-172   4.49374557e-167]
Beta Std Error: [ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
Beta Covariance: [[  6.37459471e-10  -8.57690019e-09  -2.18092934e-11  -1.13009384e-06]
 [ -8.57690019e-09   5.11732570e-07   1.30123070e-09   6.74263262e-05]
 [ -2.18092934e-11   1.30123070e-09   5.22674068e-12   1.70799469e-07]
 [ -1.13009384e-06   6.74263262e-05   1.70799469e-07   8.88444676e-03]]
Residual Variance: 0.0
Inverse Condition #: 0.0010484041422201213
Reason(s) for Halting:
  Sum of squares convergence
None
'
```

The code I am using :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg
from scipy import odr
import pickle

def planar_fit(points):
    # best-fit linear plane
    a = np.c_[points[:, 0], points[:, 1], np.ones(points.shape[0])]
    c, _, _, _ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(a, points[:, 2])  # coefficients
    # The coefficients are returned as an array beta=[a, b, c, d] from the implicit form 'a*x + b*y + c*z + d = 0'.
    beta = np.r_[c[0], c[1], -1, c[2]] / c[2]
    return beta


def odr_planar_fit(points):
    def f_3(beta, xyz):
        """ implicit definition of the plane"""
        return beta[0] * xyz[0] + beta[1] * xyz[1] + beta[2] * xyz[2] + beta[3]

    # # Coordinates of the 2D points
    x = points[:, 0]
    y = points[:, 1]
    z = points[:, 2]

    # Use least squares for initial estimate.
    beta0 = planar_fit(points)

    # Create the data object for the odr. The equation is given in the implicit form 'a*x + b*y + c*z + d = 0' and
    # beta=[a, b, c, d] (beta is the vector to be fitted). The positional argument y=1 means that the dimensionality
    # of the fitting is 1.
    lsc_data = odr.Data(np.row_stack([x, y, z]), y=1)
    # Create the odr model
    lsc_model = odr.Model(f_3, implicit=True)
    # Create the odr object based on the data, the model and the first estimation vector.
    lsc_odr = odr.ODR(lsc_data, lsc_model, beta0)
    # run the regression.
    lsc_out = lsc_odr.run()

    return lsc_out, beta0

def main():
    #import from pickle.
    with open('./points.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        points = np.array(pickle.load(f))

    # Perform the ODR
    odr_out, lstsq = odr_planar_fit(points)
    print(lstsq)
    print(odr_out.pprint())

main()
```

[The pickle containing my points.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_sYm0kzBvYPZ3AFMO8aMOPqMYbAmlXg9/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

ODR is completely fine with multidimensional data, you were going the correct direction.

You just chose bad to use the implicit version of ODR with your `f_3` definition. The problem is you have a function `A*X=0` which you try to minimize without any additional constraints. Of course, the best the optimizer can do is to minimize the magnitude of `A` towards zero - that minimizes the error the best! For the implicit optimization to work, you need to somehow introduce a constraint on magnitude of `A`, e.g. by dividing by the last number:

```
def f_3(beta, xyz):
    """ implicit definition of the plane"""
    return beta[0]/beta[3] * xyz[0] + beta[1]/beta[3] * xyz[1] + beta[2]/beta[3] * xyz[2] + 1.0
```

This way, the optimizer has no other option than to do what you wanted it to do :)

Alternatively, you can also convert your model to the explicit form `y = ax + cz + d`, which doesn't suffer from the magnitude problems (as `b == 1` all the time).

Of course, you could get additional precision by shifting your points to origin and scaling them to have a unit variance in distance.

Since I'm also about to use ODR, I was curious about its properties, so I played around to find out how precise and sensitive it is, and here's the result: https://gist.github.com/peci1/fb1cea77c41fe8ace6c0db8ef82539a3 .

I tested both implicit and exlicit ODR, with and without normalization, and with initial guess either from LSQ or a bad one (to see how sensitive to the guess it is). It looked like this on your data:
[image: ODR tests]
Basically, the yellow and grey planes are the implicit fits without normalization, which came out pretty bad, and the rest of ODR fits is more or less the same. You can see the ODR fits differ a bit from the (faint blue) LSQ fit (which is expected).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the `odr` it is not made for 3D data, but I might be wrong here. As this is a simple plane fit, I suggest to use simple `leastsq`. Moreover, note that you do not really have 4 free parameters as you can divide `a * x + b * y + c * z + d = 0` e.g. by `d` providing `a' * x + b' * y + c' * z + 1 = 0` ( if `d` is not zero ).

If instead we write the plane in the form: all points `P` for which`(P - p0) * n = 0` we already have the odr function for free. One can simplify by assuming that the plane offset vector `p0 = s * n` is the scaled normal vector. Like this there are 3 free parameters, the scale `s` and the direction angles of the normal vector `(theta, phi)`.

The according fit looks as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq 
from random import random

# for rotating test data
def y_mx( theta ):
    out = np.array( [ np.cos( theta ),0, np.sin( theta ),  0, 1, 0, -np.sin( theta ),0, np.cos( theta ) ] )
    return out.reshape( 3, 3)


# for rotating test data
def z_mx( theta ):
    out = np.array( [ np.cos( theta ), np.sin( theta ), 0, -np.sin( theta ), np.cos( theta ), 0, 0, 0, 1 ] )
    return out.reshape( 3, 3)


# for test data
def make_plane( theta, phi, px, py, pz, n=100 ):
    points=[]
    for i in range( n ):
        x = 1 - 2 * random( )
        y = 1 - 2 * random( )
        z = 0.15 * ( 1 - 2 * random() )
        points += [ np.array( [ x, y, z] ) ]
    points = np.array( points)

    points = [ np.array( [px, py, pz ] ) + np.dot( z_mx( phi ),  np.dot( y_mx( theta ) , p ) ) for p in points  ]
    return np.array( points )


# residual function for leastsq
# note the plane equation is (P - p0) n = 0 if P is member of plane
# and n is normal vector of plane directly provides the normal distance function
# moreover p0 can be chosen to be s * n
def residuals( params, points ):
    scale, theta, phi = params
    nVector = np.array( [ np.sin( theta ) * np.cos( phi ), np.sin( theta ) * np.sin( phi ), np.cos( theta ) ] )
    p0 = scale * nVector
    diff = [ np.dot( p - p0, nVector ) for p in points]
    return diff


# some test data
pnts = make_plane( 1.5, 1.49, .15, .2, .33)

#and the fit
guess=[ 0, 0, 0 ]
bestfit, err = leastsq( residuals, guess, pnts )

#the resulting normal vectot and offset
nVectorFit = np.array( [ np.sin( bestfit[1] ) * np.cos( bestfit[2] ), np.sin( bestfit[1] ) * np.sin( bestfit[2] ), np.cos( bestfit[1] ) ] )
p0Fit = bestfit[0] * nVectorFit

# converting to standard plane equation
a = nVectorFit[0] / nVectorFit[1]
c = nVectorFit[2] / nVectorFit[1]
d = bestfit[0] / nVectorFit[1]

# plane equation data
X = np.linspace( -.6, .6, 20 )
Z = np.linspace( -.6, .6, 20 )
XX, ZZ = np.meshgrid( X, Z )
YY = -a * XX - c * ZZ + d

#plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
# original data
ax.scatter( pnts[:,0], pnts[:,1] , pnts[:,2])
# offset vector
ax.plot( [0, p0Fit[0] ], [0, p0Fit[1] ], [0, p0Fit[2] ], color = 'r')
# fitted plane
ax.plot_wireframe(XX, YY, ZZ , color = '#9900bb')

ax.set_xlim( [-1,1] )
ax.set_ylim( [-1,1] )
ax.set_zlim( [-1,1] )
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
plt.show()
```

Providing

[image: Fit]

Blue points is noisy data, purple is the fitted plane, and red the offset vector.

It is easy to see that the for the case here `y = a * x + c * z + d`, `a, c, d` are calculated straight forward from the fit result.